# Passing a char* argument to a C++ DLL function from a C# app

Tags: c#, dll, oculus

I am trying to use a dll function declared as `void Process(char* data)` from C#.

The dll provides various functions to operate an OculusRift.
This function is supposed to display in the Oculus the data image and it is used by another fully functioning app.

In my code, I generate a byte[] from a Bitmap image, then I convert it into other things (char[], append a StringBuilder,...) aiming at passing this to the `Process` function.

I load this process function from a DLL via `LoadLibrary` (to load the DLL) + `GetProcAdress` (to access the function). I can't use `DLLImport` because I want to be as close as possible to the way the interface of the other app (written in C++) works with the DLL.

I tried using 
`[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void Process([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder data);`

or simply 
`[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void Process(StringBuilder data);`

(I read passing a string/StringBuilder could do the trick because it's marshaled by default as a char*). As a result I had the full string passed as an argument to the DLL and not a char*.

I tried to pass an IntPtr as argument too, using Marshal Copy and

`[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private delegate void Process(IntPtr data);`. 
As a result I had a Memory Access Violation Exception.

I then tried various things using unsafe code such as implementing the whole data creation process from the other app (for my purposes I only need a simplified version) or creating the data as I want in a char[] and then copying this char[] to a char* which I passed to

`[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private unsafe delegate void Process(char* data);`

This resulted in stack overflow exceptions from stackalloc and in Memory Access Violation Exception.

At this point, I think I'm missing something and need your help. I don't know if there is some kind of lock causing the Memory Exception Error (I made sure the image is of the right size), I don't know if I've not fully misunderstood the marshaling process, etc.

I hope I've been explicit enough concerning my problem.

Comment: *In my code, I generate a byte[] from a Bitmap image, then I convert it into other things (char[], append a StringBuilder,...)* Do you use [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art) perhaps? Because an image is an image, a `string` is a `string`...

Comment: Actually, i get a byte[] from a bitmap image. Then, thanks to `Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(bytes)` i can convert those bytes into char. I don't try to load a BitMap image directly to char.

Comment: An image is an image, a `string` is a `string`... You don't mix the two. Your method probably accepts a `byte[]` parameter. What is the source of this image? Is it in the right format?

Comment: The method accepts only char*, then the Oculus dll renders an image from argument into the Oculus. The c++ app which uses this dll too compute each pixels of a new image and then store those digits into a char *. Personnaly I chose to open  an image in order to get each of its pixels values (because i don't need to calculate some) and then proceed like the c++ app does.

Comment: In C/C++ `char*` is used both for strings and for byte arrays...

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know that. Still not working though :-( Memory Access Violation.

Comment: Ok, this exception was my bad: it came from not computing the proper size for the image. Now everything seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C **char** is used to represent bytes because in C the type **byte** doesn't exists. Or is just equal to the **char** type.

So to map from C#:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void Process([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]byte[] data);
```

or

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate void Process(byte[] data);
```

Regards